# Google Sheets Apps Script - Input box on mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-input, prompt

I have the following code included on a spreadsheet that I will be using primarily on a iPhone, but also periodically on a PC.

```
function displayPrompt() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();   
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var result = ui.prompt("Please enter email body");

//Get the button that the user pressed.
var button = result.getSelectedButton();
var message = {
to: "someone@somewhere.com",
subject: sheetName,
body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find attached the quote 
that you requested.\n" + 
result.getResponseText() + "\nThank you,\nMe",
name: "My Name",
attachments: 
[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF)
.setName("Quote")]  
}
if (button === ui.Button.OK) {
Logger.log("The user clicked the [OK] button.");
Logger.log(result.getResponseText());
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
} else if (button === ui.Button.CLOSE) {
Logger.log("The user clicked the [Cancel] button.");
}

}
```

I can't get the script to run on my phone because of - I think - the prompt box. So my question is this...can I run any kind of input/prompt box on the mobile version of Google Sheets that would work on PC as well, or could I possibly add an if statement to run a different script on mobile than on PC?

Comment: What happens if you open the spreadsheet on your mobile browser?

Comment: It will be executed on the mobile app.